# Are there any tools for testing installer packages?

Tags: windows, testing, installation, automation

As part of our nightly build on windows, an installer package is created using NSIS. I would like to automatically test the "correctness" of the installer.

This might be things like:

- Checking the platform of dll files.
- Checking the install folder.
- Testing the uninstall function doesn't leave any files behind.
- Checking registry keys are created in the right location.

Are there any tools or techniques that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think VM's or automated processes to push the package to the VM is an answer in itself. The real problem here is 'How do you know the integrated / deployed product will work?' I think the only answer to that question at this point would be to then have automated processes to test the application itself in the deployed state.

Comment: You make a number of good points. But there are a number of cases where the application will run when it should not, eg WoW64. Also the application does usually care if it can be uninstalled correctly or not.

Comment: True.  Windows Installer has the concept of validation.  It doesn't actually run the installer, it just checks the MSI database for issues using a series of ICE's ( unit tests ).  I will say in my experience the declarative nature of MSI lends itself to very predictable behavior.  Especially if you avoid writing custom actions and run your validation.

Comment: Still, this validation doesn't answer the question of 'will it work? did I deploy the right things?'   I have yet to find a simple solution to this problem.